# svn checkin time-stamp in hudson

Tags: svn, hudson

HI

I am having a small issue 
i want the SVN_Revision number and the corresponding time-stamp of the checkout revision in Hudson build 
I could get the revision number using the SVN_REVISION  environment variable,but there is no such variable to get the time-stamp of the commited version ? 
Is there any variable in hudson using which i can get the time-stamp of the checked out  revision number

Thanks in advance 
Chandu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct support in Hudson for that information.

The closest way to get that data would be using a pre-build step with the irght svn command (assuming `SVN_REVISION` is already set at that stage)

Comment: Note: I will also monitor your question on http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/svn-checkin-time-stamp-in-hudson-td3207290.html to include any answer there.

Comment: Hi VonC Thanks for your reply, please do advice me on the pre-build step for getting the Checkout revision time-stamp in hudson.

Comment: @Chandu: if SVN_REVISION is available in pre-build step (not tested), you would execute the command line `svn propget svn:date --revprop -r$SVN_REVISION URL` to get the date property associated with the commit.